# EF DbContext VS Session lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework code first for an ecommerce website. I want to store the basket in the session. I'm using Ninject to manage the lifecycle of the DbContext, and I've set the scope of this to be per request.

My problem is that because the lifetime of the basket is per session, but the lifetime of the DbContext is per request - the basket isn't then attached to each request's new DbContext instance.

I could re-instantiate the basket on each request, but this seems quite inefficient as it would be getting all the basket details for every request.

I could reattach the session's basket at the start of each request. This seems to be the best solution from what I can see.

What's the recommended way to deal with this scenario?

I've found other questions / posts which ask about the scope of the DbContext, and the recommendations are to use an IOC container to use the same DbContext per request. I'm already doing this though - I've not really found an answer to the question about how to keep the per-request DbContext attached to the longer lifetime of an entity in the Session State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way would be to not to store persistence objects in the basket but rather some POCOs (plain objects) that:

- can be used to show the contents of the basket efficiently
- still contain database IDs so that when the order is accepted you can use IDs to retrieve database entites in the current instance of the database context

Attaching and reattaching persistence objects could possibly work, however when you finally have a farm of application servers and decide to persist your session in a database, persistence objects would have to be serialized and deserialized, which could lead to other suble issues (as long as your session is persisted by the inproc session provider you are not seeing these issues).

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between my 'basket' and your description of the POCO object. I still need to persist that data across requests.

Very good point about the multiple web servers - I'll bare this in mind when deciding which route to go.

Comment: @Dan: I don't know what your "basket" is. I assumed it contains persistence objects, as you say you want to "attach it". There is no need to "persist" data across requests if you put it into the `Session` container and if you do so, put POCOs there rather than persistence objects.

Comment: My basket is just an EF entity. I'm using Code First, so this is literally just a POCO object. I'm storing a reference to it in the session. I'm unsure of your definition of 'persistence objects'. I'm putting it in the session, so that is persistent across multiple requests. I can also commit it to the database as it's an EF entity (ie. referenced my DbContext class). It's still just a POCO object though - even though EF can track it.

Comment: @Dan: technically it is POCO but what you really get from EF is a **proxy** to your POCO where navigation properties are autoimplemented to allow lazy loading. In reality, this is not POCO then. If ASP tries to serialize it with the database session provider, you get into trouble.

Comment: So it sounds like I can just store an instance of my existing Basket class in the session, but never attach it to the DbContext. That way it remains just a POCO object. There's no point in creating another identical class for this. I'll actually still have to attach it when writing to the database (or create a copy of it, which I think is what you suggested), but then only attach it (or the copy) whilst I write it to the database, ensuring that it doesn't stay attached...

Comment: ... I have a Basket.Commit method which internally calls SaveChanges(). So I could just have this do the attach and deattach. Does this sound like what you mean? I don't think I'll need to copy if I'm explicitly detaching after SaveChanges().

Comment: Instead of attaching/deattaching, use ID do retrieve corresponding entity from the database. If basket doesn't contain any navigation properties, then yes, it is POCO and can be stored in session. If this is otherwise, there are navigation properties, then you could bump into issues storing it into session.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll probably continue using my basket class, but just never associate that instance with EF. Then, as you say, use the ID to get/update a different instance at commit to database time. Thanks for your help. Will mark this as the answer.